# How can I position Position MatSnackBar module in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to position the `MatSnackbar` module to appear at the top of my page.

I have tried using the `config` to add `customclass`. Here is my code:

**component.ts**

```
let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
config.duration = 50000;
config.panelClass = ['red-snackbar']
this.snackBar.open("Please fill all the details before proceeding.", null, config);
```

**.css**

```
.red-snackbar{
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 54px;
}
```

But it is not working. Is it possible to re-position the MatSnackbar?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can determine the `verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition` as specified by the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBarConfig)

ts:

```
openSnackBar(message: string, action: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 2000,
      // here specify the position
      verticalPosition: 'top'
    });
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yer8ju)

Comment: Thanks, this does work. I have another question, can I apply some position styling too, for example I want to show it not at absolute top but say 50px from top. So, can I somehow give margin-top to it?

Comment: the link directs to a non-existent page :/

Answer (score 14):

To position the snackbar use position values

```
            this.snackBar.open(message.text, action, {
                duration: this.timeOut,
                verticalPosition: 'bottom', // 'top' | 'bottom'
                horizontalPosition: 'end', //'start' | 'center' | 'end' | 'left' | 'right'
                panelClass: ['red-snackbar'],
            });
```

and  to change color, in your style.css define the red-snackbar:

```
 .red-snackbar{
  background-color: rgb(153, 50, 50);
  color:lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

https://www.coditty.com/code/angular-material-display-multiple-snackbars-messages-in-sequence

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering how to dynamically set the snackbar position, here is an example:

```
showSnackBar(text: string, duration = 2000, actionText = 'Fechar', horizontalPosition = 'center'): MatSnackBarRef<SimpleSnackBar> {
    return this.snackBar.open(text, actionText, {
      duration: duration,
      // Cast the variable to MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition
      horizontalPosition: horizontalPosition as MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition
    });
  }
```

And import MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition from:

```
import { MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition } from "@angular/material/snack-bar";
```

Comment: Good example, saves me some times, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vertical position, you can fine-tune your position with:

```
.red-snackbar{
    transform: translateY(50px) !important;;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
.mat-snack-bar-container {
 margin-top: 50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is deprecated, but worked fine in Angular: 12.0.0-rc.3.

```
::ng-deep .mat-snack-bar-container {
    margin-top: 250px !important;
}
```